# MPNS Push notification server returns supressed as notification status

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, push-notification, mpns

I'm trying to send push notifications to my widows phone 8 app (Tile notification). This is the response from MPNS: **notification status : suppressed notificationChannelStatus :Active, deviceConnectionStatus:Connected**. I have checked the server response codes, and I found the following explanation:

> The push notification was received and dropped by the Push
>   Notification Service. The Suppressed status can occur if the
>   notification type was not enabled by calling BindToShellTile or
>   BindToShellToast in the client application

This is my code in client side and I am calling `BindToShellTile` method - it is getting invoked the first time the app is installed.

```
HttpNotificationChannel pushChannel;
string channelName = "TileSampleChannel";
pushChannel = HttpNotificationChannel.Find(channelName);
if (pushChannel == null) {
    pushChannel = new HttpNotificationChannel(channelName);
    // Register for all the events before attempting to open the channel.
    pushChannel.ChannelUriUpdated += new EventHandler<NotificationChannelUriEventArgs>(PushChannel_ChannelUriUpdated);
    pushChannel.ErrorOccurred += new EventHandler<NotificationChannelErrorEventArgs>(PushChannel_ErrorOccurred);  
    pushChannel.Open();               
    pushChannel.BindToShellTile();
} else {          
    pushChannel.ChannelUriUpdated += new EventHandler<NotificationChannelUriEventArgs>(PushChannel_ChannelUriUpdated);
    pushChannel.ErrorOccurred += new EventHandler<NotificationChannelErrorEventArgs>(PushChannel_ErrorOccurred);                    
    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(pushChannel.ChannelUri.ToString());
    MessageBox.Show(String.Format("Channel Uri is {0}",
    pushChannel.ChannelUri.ToString())); 
}
```

And I am able to get the channel URI successfully. Why am I always getting suppressed state? I have tested this on device and I have checked that battery is not low. The tile is also pinned to start screen.

This is my XML

```
 string tileMessage = "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\"?>" +
                "<wp:Notification xmlns:wp=\"WPNotification\">" +
                    "<wp:Tile>" +
                      "<wp:BackgroundImage>" + TextBoxBackgroundImage.Text + "</wp:BackgroundImage>" +
                      "<wp:Count>" + TextBoxCount.Text + "</wp:Count>" +
                      "<wp:Title>" + TextBoxTitle.Text + "</wp:Title>" +
                      "<wp:BackBackgroundImage>" + TextBoxBackBackgroundImage.Text + "</wp:BackBackgroundImage>" +
                      "<wp:BackTitle>" + TextBoxBackTitle.Text + "</wp:BackTitle>" +
                      "<wp:BackContent>" + TextBoxBackContent.Text + "</wp:BackContent>" +
                   "</wp:Tile> " +
                "</wp:Notification>";
```

Comment: Can you show your XML message?

Comment: @kubakista I have added my XML..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Verify that your notification content length,content type and headers are correct.

For Tile notifications you need the following headers :

```
sendNotificationRequest.Headers.Add("X-WindowsPhone-Target", "token");
sendNotificationRequest.Headers.Add("X-NotificationClass", "1");
```

and before headers, set the content length and type as follows :

```
sendNotificationRequest.ContentLength = notificationMessage.Length;
sendNotificationRequest.ContentType = "text/xml";
```

If you don't specify the headers correctly that can make Notification Status as Suppressed. This might be useful.

Comment: Thank you.. The problem was with notificationMessage.Length, I was not sure of the encoding used..Got it working!

Comment: can you tell me what was wrong there? i m also struglling with encoding type